# Teamcity + NUnit - exclude assembly from dll

Tags: namespaces, nunit, teamcity, specflow

Currently, I am working with a new set of unit tests in my project.

Let's say that on TeamCity I have a build that goes at night and one that goes after every commit.

In both, I have one same build step.
It is a NUnit runner which run tests from three dll files.
In one of them I have my new tests which are located in the same directory (same namespace).

I would like my tests not to run on this build, which moves all the time.

I know that NUnit command line allows excluding categories. Unfortunately, my tests are generated using specflow and it is not effective to add a category to all scenarios.

Is it possible to exclude tests with specified namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use option `--where "test!=some.name.space"